# 404 Error when authenticating a Azure Static Web Application

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I have created a static web application in Azure. This is just a plain site with only HTML pages. I am able to deploy and access the application.

The issue is when I try to integrate Azure Active Directory with this service. My staticwebapp.config.json is as follows.

```
{
  "routes":[
    {
      "route": "/login",
      "rewrite": "/.auth/login/aad"
    },
    {
        "route": "/*",
        "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
    }
  ],
  "auth": {
    "identityProviders": {
      "azureActiveDirectory": {
        "registration": {
          "openIdIssuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id removed>",
          "clientIdSettingName": "<client id value>",
          "clientSecretSettingName": "<client secret value>"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "responseOverrides": {
    "401": {
      "redirect": "/login",
      "statusCode": 302
    }
  }
}
```

After this, when I try to access any page, it gets redirected to /login and I get a 404 page. I expected it to go to azure authentication page (due to the redirect rule). Are there any other configurations that needs to be done for authenticating a static web application?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 8):

One thing to double check here would be the `clientIdSettingName` and `clientSecretSettingName` fields.

These are not the actual values, but rather **references** to [SWA settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings#configure-application-settings). Reason for doing it this way is to ensure no plain-text secrets are committed to source control.

So, given literal values

```json
"clientIdSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_ID",
"clientSecretSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"
```

Azure portal should be set up with something like this:
[image: azure portal showing SWA configuration parameter names]

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-custom?tabs=aad#configure-a-custom-identity-provider) clearly mentions this step, but I missed the referential nature of this setting upon first couple of readthroughs. Ultimately, variable names gave it away.

Comment: And here I was wondering why the property is called `...SettingName`. m(